# Only User Upload image Http Error

Tags: images, uploads, customization

I've search all over and tried a bunch of things. Basically, as admin I can use the featured image and upload with no issues. When i switch roles I cannot upload images, i get an HTTP error.

- I did set the upload_files & unfiltered_upload
- I did reduce the size of the image
- I double checked file permissions
- Host says it's wordpress not the server

Anyone have any idea what this could be?

Comment: What is that error? Copy and paste it _verbatim_.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out, I had the user assigned to the wrong role, so upload_files works. FYI the error was verbatum HTTP ERROR. If the error would have been permission denied I would have figured it out sooner.